# Include specific Bootstrap less file, when using bootstrap gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using:

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '~> 3.3'
```

I'd like to make a custom CSS alert class based on bootstraps existing alert-warning.

Digging down into bootstrap's alerts.less, I see alerts are defined via:

```
.alert-warning {
  .alert-variant(@alert-warning-bg; @alert-warning-border; @alert-warning-text);
}
```

So ideally I would like to do something like:

```
.my-warning {
  .alert-variant(red; @alert-warning-border; @alert-warning-text);
}
```

However to do that I need to pull in alerts.less and variables.less via @include.

How do I do that given I'm using the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap you can read:

> Please see the [less-rails-bootstrap-test](http://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap-test) repo for examples that
>   customize the CSS output by using LESS. The "CSS Tests Suites" section
>   of the README and code is what you want to focus on. Also, check out
>   the [LESS syntax](http://lesscss.org/).

Then you will find: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap-test#basic-less-bootstrap. So in your situation:

```
/*
 *= require basic_less/index
*/


@import "twitter/bootstrap";

.my-warning {
  .alert-variant(red; @alert-warning-border; @alert-warning-text);
}
```